# how remove the backslash ("\") in the json response using php?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I try to add a row of mysql query into JSON whit php. I use this code:

```
public function lugaresCercanos($lng, $lat, $distance){
$result=mysql_query("SELECT nombre, distancia FROM Lugar ORDER BY distancia ASC");
$info=array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
        array_push($info,$row);
    }
    return json_encode($info);
```

This returns a JSONObject, but I'm not sure.

```
    class resultado_final {
public $logstatus = "";
public $lugares_cercanos = "";}

$result_final = new resultado_final();
if($db->login($usuario,$passw)){
$result_final->logstatus = "0";}else{
$result_final->logstatus = "1";}
$result_final->lugares_cercanos = $lista;
echo json_encode($result_final);
```

This code print this:

```
{"logstatus":"1","lugares_cercanos":"[{\"nombre\":\"Rio Amazonas\",\"distancia\":\"5119.000\"},{\"nombre\":\"Swissotel \",\"distancia\":\"5823.000\"},{\"nombre\":\"Laguna de Yaguarcocha\",\"distancia\":\"71797.000\"}]"}
```

why the rows of the query are separated by backslashes?
how  remove the backslashes?
Thanks alot!

Comment: The \ is to escape the quotes (") that are part of the response.

Answer (score 16):

The \ is to escape the quotes (") that are part of the response.

Use `stripslashes()` to strip these out.

When a string wrapped in quotes contains quotes, they have to be escaped. The escape character in php is `\`.

Answer (score 13):

Try

```
json_encode($arr, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

or

```
echo str_replace('\/','/',json_encode($mydatas));
```

(if unescape doesn't work)
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: This worked for me: echo str_replace('\/','/',json_encode($mydatas));

Answer (score 6):

Stop double-encoding your data. Put everything together in one large structure and then encode *only that*.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone wants to remove the backslashes and also pretty print the JSON data, the following can be used:

```
json_encode($my_array, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I resolve it.

```
$info=array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
        array_push($info,$row);
    }
    $info;
$result_final->lugares_cercanos = $info;
```

Print this:

```
{"logstatus":"1","lugares_cercanos":[{"nombre":"Rio Amazonas","distancia":"5119.000"}{"nombre":"Swissotel Quito","distancia":"5823.000"}{"nombre":"Laguna de Yaguarcocha","distancia":"71797.000"}]}
```