# Fetch String with special character from json using JSONObject

Tags: java, json

I have a JSON object with special character in it.
The format is as follows:

```
"field1": "result1", "field2": "\uabc\udef\ughi"
```

I get the string for each of the keys as

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
String s1 = jsonObj.getString("field1");
String s2 = jsonObj.getString("field2");
```

When I print s2, I get weird characters as output. I know, "\u" is doing all the weirdness and I do not want that. I just want to get the string for field2 as it is. Sadly, I cannot modify the JSON object at source.
Any solution to this scenario.

Comment: Looks like you should be able to fix it by encoding it then decoding it if I read this correctly. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32056940/how-to-deal-with-backslashes-in-json-strings-php

Comment: if you know it's always  present in field2 then why not replace \u with empty string?