# Can someone please explain to me what the "\" inside this php array do?

Tags: php

Inside an AJAX call, there is the following php code:

```
$jsonOutput =
                "{
                            id: \"0\",
                            name: \"dauerreservierung\",
                            startDate: new Date('".date("Y-m-d", strtotime('-100 year',
                            $today))."'),
                            endDate: new Date('".date("Y-m-d", strtotime('+20 year',
                            $today))."'),
                            \"color\": \"#FF0000\",
                        }";
```

I really have problems following this syntax. What are all those slashes doing there? Why are the " connected to the slashes?
And: Is an associative array created here?

Comment: They are escaping the double quotes since the entire block is already surrounded by double quotes.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php

Comment: no matter how you skin it, this json is not valid json, so your mileage will definitely vary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This variable is not an array, it's a string containing a JSON object.

In PHP, if you want to put quotes in a string, you have to escape them using `\`

Examples :

```
$my_life = 'I\'m eating an apple';
$json = "{\"id\": 1, \"value\": 42}";
```

You should try to `echo $jsonOutput;` to see what is happening

Answer (score 1):

The backslash (`\`) is a special character in both PHP and JSON. Both languages use it to escape special characters in strings and in order to represent a backslash correctly in strings you have to prepend another backslash to it, both in PHP and JSON.

For more details refer this PHP manual http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single

and refer to this [StackOverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32056940/how-to-deal-with-backslashes-in-json-strings-php) as well.

Answer (score 0):

if you are consuming this response in PHP, use

```
json_decode(input_string)
```

to get (backslashes) out of the json

If you are consuming in javascript, use

```
string.replace(/\\\//g, "/"); or JSON.parse(input_string)
```

Comment: if this ever gets to a php json_decode, it will fail.

Comment: Yes, you need to make sure you follow the generic pattern while encoding and decoding the json