# json error with character '\' (unexpected token)

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have this code:

```
PHP
function print_json(){
    //code...
    $rows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $images = json_encode($rows);
    echo $images;
}
JAVASCRIPT
var json = JSON.parse('<?php print_json(); ?>');
console.log(json);
```

The console error is: "Uncaught SintaxError: Unexpected token in JSON at position 188 at JSON.parse () at name of my page"

This error appeared for the first time when the extraction contained some base64 images, I did some tests and I found that it also shows errors with strings like 'hi \ hi'.
The problem is the character '\', why json_encode don't fix the escape problem with that character?

Comment: Have you tried looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32056940/how-to-deal-with-backslashes-in-json-strings-php?rq=1 ?

Comment: Shouldn't need to use JSON.parse. When printed in a script tag will automatically be read as array or object by javascript if you don't quote the output

Comment: Can you post result of function print_json()?

Comment: @charlietfl You have indicated the right solution

Comment: But also thanks to all the others for the interest.