# How to treat strings in ConvertFrom-Json as literals?

Tags: json, powershell, escaping, string-literals

I'm importing a set of configuration values from a file in JSON format using the following:

```
$configFileContent = Get-Content -Path run.config | ConvertFrom-Json
```

This produces a result that among other things, contains the following (the contents of the variable `$configFileContent`):

```
{
    "config-values":{
        "path":"..\temp-path"
    }
}
```

Next, I try to access the value of *path* from that config as follows:

```
$conf = $configFileContent.'config-values'
$tempPath = $conf.'path'
```

..but this fails due to the characters `\t` in `..\temp-path` being interpreted as an escape sequence representing a *Tab* instead. This is clear by printing the contents of `$conf`, which is now:

```
path
----
..      emp-path
```

As you can see, the value of `Path` is `.. <tab> emp-path` instead of `..\temp-path`, as intended. Obviously this causes trouble later when I'm trying to use the variable `$tempPath` as an actual path.

How can I make Powershell interpret this as intended - i.e., treat strings as literals here?

Comment: It's the JSON parser that does this. Backslashes in JSON need to be escaped (`"path":"..\\temp-path"`). [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32056940/1630171). Essentially you need to fix your input data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand this may not be the answer you are looking for.
But the quick fix is to use a double backslash in your JSON file

It is also a common workaround in all other languages

```
{
    "config-values":{
        "path":"..\\temp-path"
    }
}
```

Comment: I see, and this makes sense. I guess I didn't consider that it could be an actual property of the JSON language, but it clearly is. Thanks for your input.