# Insert \ character using JSON+PHP in MySql

Tags: php, json, character

I string contain \ character.
All character inserted properly but this '\'.

My json created is like this : [{"desc":"\"}]
PHP Code :

```
$mparajson = '{"arrayofvalues":false,"recordcount":1,"rows":[{"desc":"\\"}]}';

$jsall  = array();
$jsone  = array();
$jsall_all = json_decode($mparajson, true);
$jsall =  $jsall_all["rows"];

$x = 0;
$jsone=$jsall[$x];
```

$jsone is null

Comment: Where does `$x` come from and what does it contain?

Comment: $x is for loop 
in this condition its value $x = 0

Answer (score 0):

Make it like below (**Four backslashes**).

```
$mparajson = '{"arrayofvalues":false,"recordcount":1,"rows":[{"desc":"\\\\"}]}';
```

You can test this as follows,

```
$sample_array = ['arrayofvalues' => false, 'recordcount' => 1, 'rows' => ['desc' => '\\']];

echo '<pre>';
print_r(json_decode(json_encode($sample_array), true));
exit;
```

**Ref:** [How to deal with backslashes in json strings php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32056940/how-to-deal-with-backslashes-in-json-strings-php)

Comment: Why the redundant json_decode?  Do you mean print_r(json_decode($sample_array, TRUE));    https://snipboard.io/A2v4QJ.jpg

Comment: See the reference link for more detailed information about `json_encode()` and `json_decode()`.

Comment: Ahhh, hard to see with this formatting.  Just an odd way of writing it out I guess.

Comment: `$mparajson = '{"arrayofvalues":false,"recordcount":1,"rows":[{"desc":"\\"}]}';` How did you get this line of code. Provide the details about before this line of code.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON string is not formatted right.  Try this:

```
$mparajson = '{"arrayofvalues":false,"recordcount": 1, "rows":{"desc":"something with slashes \\\\"}}';
```

When escaping in JSON you have to use a backslash.  Since you had two back slashes, you need two out in front.