# Wordpress json_encode and json_decode with quotes, slashes, emojis

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I have a data array such as

```
array(
    'question' => 'Title here',
    'options'  => array( 'Option here', 'Option here' )
)
```

Now, the title/options can have special characters such as "quotes" and also 'single ones', along with maybe/slashes as well or emojis.

Unfortunately, upon adding these to the data and encoding, I can't decode it.
Well, rather, WordPress just returns empty.

```
$encoded = json_encode( $poll_data );
// save, retrieve from DB
$decoded = json_decode( $retrieved );
```

Above, `$retrieved`  is:

```
{"question":"This is \"some quotes\" and also \'single quotes\'","options":["Here is an emoji: ud83dude06","With some slashes/too and back\\as well"]}
```

But $decoded ends up empty/null

I've tried various sorts of add/stipslashes and also htmlspecialentities to no avail

Comment: You have to escape your backslashes. Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32056940/how-to-deal-with-backslashes-in-json-strings-php

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deal with backslashes in json strings php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32056940/how-to-deal-with-backslashes-in-json-strings-php)

Comment: @kuh-chan it actually fail's with just a single ' or double quote, even with no slashes

Comment: Your example looks fine, if you escape your backslashes: https://3v4l.org/sSn6m (Just the backslash to escape the backslash and the backslash. So you'll need 4 instead of 2 backslashes:)

Comment: Have you tried setting it to UTF-8 before decoding? $var = htmlentities( $retrieved, ENT_QUOTES, "utf-8" ); $decoded = json_decode( $var );

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So, this ended up being the proper way to clean the string before json_encode

```
$data = wp_encode_emoji( addslashes( stripslashes( htmlspecialchars ( $poll_question ) ) ) )
json_encode( $data );
```

Seems crazy, but it works with quotes, double quotes, slashes, and emojis.