# Javascript base64 image url replaces all "\" for spaces?

Tags: javascript, css, image, base64

I am loosing my mind! Why is the browser stripping all of the `\` in my base64 data?

I log the data and it has them before I put the url into the element but, then it looks like this (with spaces instead of `\`'s)

[image]

```
        $('#content').append(`
          <div id="pool_${cc}" class="pool" style="position:relative;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;right:0px;margin-top:${n == 0 ? '15' : '25'}px;">
            <div class="black win" style="position:relative;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;right:0px;height:100px;background:#000000a6;">
              <div class="coin" id="cc_${cc}" style="position:absolute;top:25px;left:-25px;width:50px;height:50px;background-image:url(${r.cc[cc]});background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:50px auto;background-position:center;"></div>
              <div style="position:absolute;top:8px;left:40px;line-height:28px;width:calc(100% - 155px);">
                <b>
                  ${(cc == r.coin ? `<b style="color:#00a2e3;font-family:black;font-style:italic;margin-right:4px;"><i class="fas fa-caret-right" style="font-style:italic;"></i><i class="fas fa-caret-right" style="font-style:italic;"></i> ${cc.toUpperCase()}</b>` : cc.toUpperCase())}
                </b>
                <div style="font-size:10px;">
                  <div style="display:inline-block;margin-right:10px;"><span style="opacity:0.5;">version:</span> 0.0.1</div> 
                  <div style="display:inline-block;margin-right:10px;"><span style="opacity:0.5;">Date:</span> Thu Mar 07 2024 15:11:48</div>
                  <div style="display:inline-block;margin-right:10px;"><span style="opacity:0.5;">Proven:</span> ${!undetermined}</div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="switchCoin btn1" style="color:#cccccc;background:#00000038;right:15px;">SWITCH</div>
              ${undetermined && `<div class="deleteCoin btn1" style="color:#cccccc;background:#00000038;right:65px;">DELETE</div>`}
            </div>
          </div>`
        );
```

**This Works fine:** `$('#cc_' + cc).css('backgroundImage', 'url(' + r.cc[cc] + ')');` so do the special quotes mess it up?

Comment: ``\`` is an escape char. Where does the uri come from? JSON? then that could be it

Comment: base64 doesn't have ```\```. But it can have `/`. Are you referring to those?

Comment: yep JSON @mplungjan, how does this `multi-line-string-element` strip the backslashes? is there a way to do it all in the multi-line instead of doing it after the el is appended?

Comment: yes @trincot, you are correct, I have toothache, I'm tired and dyslexic, thank you for the correction!

Comment: It would be helpful if you could make a runnable snippet that reproduces the issue, using minimal HTML (removing all the irrelevant HTML), a small base64 value assignment to the relevant variable, ...Etc.

Comment: tomorrow I will. I need a very small image as b64 as mine are huge!

Comment: [Likely dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32056940/how-to-deal-with-backslashes-in-json-strings-php)

Comment: Tried to reproduce the relevant part of your snippet here, can't reproduce the problem though: https://jsfiddle.net/xdcLmuta/ (Base64 URL for the small red dot image taken from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#HTML)