# Unterminated object at character 29

Tags: android, json, firebase-cloud-messaging

Trying to decode json from fcm when there are no **slashes** on the json value it works by not with a slash. Below is the json composition part from the **php** script

**This works**

```
$body="d";
$path="www.google.com";
$msg = array('body'=>$body,'path'=>$path);
```

**This Doesnt**

```
$body="d";
$path="www.google.com/images";
$msg = array('body'=>$body,'path'=>$path);
```

**Json outupt from php script that doesnt works**

```
{"data":{"body":"d","path":"www.google.com\/images"},"to":"\/topics\/test"}
```

**App Try Block**

```
try {
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData().toString());

Log.e(TAG, "Data Payload: " + json.get("body"));
                                   newmessafe(json.get("body").toString(),json.getString("path").toString());

} catch (Exception e) {

Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: i get this error Unterminated object at character 29

Comment: There's a `}` missing at the end.

Comment: Updated. if i there are no / in the path filed no exception is raised

Comment: Thats because the "\" character isnt needed infront of the "/" or it will create "www.google.comimages" instead of "www.google.com/images"

Comment: @Ellisan "\" gets added to the url after i have encoed it into json from a php array

Comment: what about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14209052/how-remove-the-backslash-in-the-json-response-using-php)

Comment: @Ellisan the exception is raised when i try to parse json see the try block above. In the json that i get url is stuctured correctly like www.google.com/images